# Passing in multiple arguments in VBA to run a Python script

Tags: python, vba, quotes

I have a very simple VBA script that will run a Python script, which has arguments specified (which are folder paths, that contain spaces).

Code is below

```vb
Dim path As String
path = Left(pdocinfo.path, InStrRev(pdocinfo.path, "\")) ' e.g C:\Temp\City Addresses

Dim pyLocation As String
pyLocation = "C:\Temp\filePath.py"

Dim strReports As String
strReports = path & "Reports\"

Dim strImages As String
strImages = path & "Images\"
Dim shellvar As Long
shellvar = shell("C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\python.exe " & pyLocation & " " & path & " " & strImages & " " & strReports , vbNormalFocus)
```

However, when the Python script is run, the file paths (`strImages`, `strReports` and `path`) do not get parsed in correctly because they contain spaces within the folder path.

What's the correct way for Python to interpret multiple arguments that are dynamic variables which also contain spaces?

Edit:
I have tried the following, following on from the comment below

```
shellvar = Shell("C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\python.exe " & pyLocation & " " & """" & path & """" & " " & """" & strImages & """" & " " & """" & strReports & """", vbNormalFocus)
```

the result from the python script is
[image]

The result I would like is

```
Argument 0: C:\Temp\filePath.py
Argument 1: "C:\Temp\City Addresses"
Argument 2: "C:\Temp\City Addresses\Images"
Argument 3: "C:\Temp\City Addresses\Reports"
```

Comment: You are probably going to have to surround those with double quotes. & """" & strImages & """" &  There are four double quotes to produce a single double quote.

Answer (score 2):

Surround those with double quotes.

```
shellvar = shell("C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\python.exe " & pyLocation & " " & """" & path & """" & " " & """" & strImages & """" & " " & """" & strReports & """", vbNormalFocus)
```

Comment: I've tried that but the parameters that are used within python is not correct. I've updated the questions to show your example as well as a screenshot of the result.